# TypeError when iterate over DiGraph()

Tags: python, networkx

Hii!
I want to get the time execution of my function ( test(G) ). when I
use Timer I need to write the type of my object : "test(% ?? )" %G
which is DiGraph here. How can I do that?

```
from networkx import nx

def test(G):
    for e in G.edges_iter():
        print(e)

if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(4,5)])
    t = Timer("test(% ?? )"%G,"from __main__ import test")
    print( t.timeit(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import `G` from `__main__` as well

```
import networkx as nx

def test(G):
    for e in G.edges_iter():
        print(e)

if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(4,5)])
    t = Timer("test(G)","from __main__ import test,G")
    print( t.timeit(1))
```

Note that I fixed the import statement also.

Comment: Thanks! That's weird because I had to also fixed import statement to make it work. But what's the difference between "from networkx import nx" and "import networkx as nx" ??

Comment: `from networkx import nx` means that the module `networkx` should _contain_ a function `nx`. But you don't want that, you want to call the module _itself_ `nx`.